# QuickType (Predictive Keyboard) not working with Subclass UITextInputBase and UIKeyInput

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uikeyboard, quicktypebar

In my application I have made subclass for UITextInputBase and all methods I have written for that same like in screen shot.

[image][image]

Here My issue is 
In textfield If I choose any word from quicktype without write any letter manually, method

```
- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text
```

is calling and I can get text there whatever user has selected from quicktype.

**Problem**

But Suppose If I have type 't', Quick type give me suggestion for "The" word. Now If I choose "The" word from quicktype. above method is not calling and I m not getting text which user has just selected from quick type.

Can any one please suggest if m missing anything or I can get it in other method of these subclass? I want these text without delegate methods of UITextField.

Thanks.